# <Weblogic-Validation> <BEA-2156403> <Unable to process URL, file:/C:/Workspace/../../../../src/webroot/WEB-INF/validation.xml

Tags: java, weblogic12c, java-ee-8

Having an error while runing the weblogic server :

<Jun 17, 2021 2:11:43,870 PM CDT>    <Unable to process URL, file:/C:/Workspace/../../../../src/webroot/WEB-INF/validation.xml, because java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '503: Service Unavailable'
for url: 'http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/dtds/validator_1_0.dtd'.>

My XML looks like :

Further error :

<Jun 17, 2021 2:26:16,868 PM CDT>    <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
Unable to load configuration. - Class: weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection

Comment: No error found like this in my team for any one. Help is appreciated to resolve this

Comment: My XML has :   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE form-validation PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Commons Validator Rules Configuration 1.0//EN"
          "http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/dtds/validator_1_0.dtd">